# Question about parsing text manipulation approach

Tags: java, memory, string

I need to parse a long file in Java and output the results to another file.

Since I need to average across several items, and I need to parse the file to find them, I need to store in memory the current averaged item before to output it to the results file on disk.

Is this approach ok, or am I going to have low performances with a million items file ?

**Update**: the point here is that each output item can be updated at any time while computation, since I might average an item in the beginning and in the end. So I cannot release it, and write on disk, I guess.

thanks

Comment: you can check out Apache Lucene - and use Index and Document - the mechanism caches information, and it might, in some case, improve performance.

Comment: @amit gr Ok, I don't need to create a Apache index, but to output an xml file though. Can I still use Lucene ? Can you give me more information about it ? thanks

Comment: why do you suspect performance problem? compared to what? in general if you are intensively working with files, it's worth mapping both input and output to the memory and using NIO (as opposed to classic IO) for reading/writing.

Comment: @bobah So, you are actually saying I should not keep in memory the entire output before to store to disk ? The point here is that each item in the output file can be updated at any time during the process.

Comment: You will probably get a more definite answer if you give little more detail about your application. Lucene is great but it can be overkill if you can allow your program to simply read your records into memory and your operations are rather simple. Million items is not that much after all :D On the other hand if your code is a part of a web application then ignore what I said and look into Lucene samples.

Comment: You can brute force scan one million items in a fraction of a second, If you use a Map style index it can be sub-micro-second.  You don't get much performance degradation between 10 K and 10 M items in a Map.

Comment: If you can retain all your data in memory (a box with 24 GB costs around £1,800) I would use that approach because its simpler and faster than touching the disk.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey So you are saying I can just keep the entire output in memory and output to disk only in the end

Comment: @Patrick - memory mapped file is RAM (or SWAP if no RAM left, but it is managed in the best possible way your OS can do), so you can get rid of one intermediate step by writing directly to the output file map in RAM that is automatically synchronized with HDD by OS. Of cause this is just a consideration, if your output is in text format and you need to do double->string conversion every time you update the output, then you rather cache everything in some appropriate container and then dump everything once done.

Comment: @Patrick - I thought you meant the data is too big to fit in RAM. if it not the case - you will not need it. If it is - I did something like that once, and I'll be able to look at it when I'm home, if is is the case.

Comment: @bobah @amit gr yeah, I'm wondering if it is too big to fit in RAM. But if I've understood well from your answers, the OS is taking care of this, and I should not worry too much. So, I will try with this approach and write to disk only when the process is complete.

Comment: @Patrick, I would assume this will work unless you know otherwise.  You may find that buying a system with more memory is cheaper and much faster than redeveloping your application to use disk. However if you only use 512 bytes per item, you can keep all items in memory for 1/2 GB.

Comment: From what I understand you will be fine with holding all your data in memory. Give it a try. Since its Java you are limited to 128mb by default, but you can increase that through VM parameters.

Comment: @Patrick, the OS takes care of it, but in some cases the data might be too big even for Virtual Memory - and then you'll need to use disk manually. (it is important especially if you run 32 bits... if you run 64 bits, it's highly unlikely that the data will be too big).

Comment: @m0s, In Java 6 you are limited to 1/2 of the physical memory by default.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, thanks didn't know :) Interesting fact is though I just tried outputting Runtime.maxMemory() it returned only ~250mb although this machine has 3 gigs (os windows) I guess it rises the limit when it needs to.

Comment: @mOs, Correction on a 64-bit JVM, it defaults to **1/4** of the memory. Perhaps you have a 32-bit JVM. It may have a different formula for the defualt memory size. On a 48 GB machine, the default size is 12 GB for a 64-bit JVM. ;)

Comment: This all is useless speculation as long as the OP does not tell us in which way the size of his output depends on the size of the input. Chances are that there is no dependency at all.

Comment: @Ingo @Peter Lawrey @mOs @amit gr So, I've written the code and I'm getting a "Segmentation Fault" error. What does it mean ? This is the code, in case you want to give a look: http://pastie.org/1708837

Comment: uhm, so now I've run it again and I got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: At which line of the code? BTW, instead of writing evrything in a string buffer and printing it out later, you could print (write) it right away.

Comment: @Ingo The main point of the question was that I cannot just print because the beforehand added to the output averaged items are successively updated while parsing and discovering new items from the input file.

Comment: For example the first item in the output might be updated, even just before I'm printing the last item.

Comment: @Patrick - I don't know what you are referring to, but I see that you build a StringBuffer "content" with many content.append() calls in a loop. This what you append to content you can write to the file system instead, saving the (probably gigantic) string buffer to be build.

Comment: @Ingo Yeah, I would like to do it, but I cannot progressively print the content because it might be that the first item in the output file needs to be updated after printing (I'm also averaging time..).

Comment: In other terms, I'm progressively averaging the centroids when I discover new items while parsing the source file. I need to update them, after creation. Probably I should scan the file differently, and look first for all docs with the same event..  but in this way I should scan the entire collection for each event, not sure it is a good idea.

Comment: No, you DONT update the StringBuffer. You construct it, then immediately write it to disk. Therefore, you can write it right away. Period.

Comment: @Ingo hey, sorry I guess I'm missing something here. If I write the temporary output file to disk, then I need to load it back into memory to update an old centroid ?

Comment: @Patrick, sorry, I have no idea what a centroid is. In the code you posted, I see: a string buffer is filled in a for loop, and then it is immediately written to disk. I say it the last time: the data in the stringbuffer are not updated anyhow, but they surely need memory. Therefore, I suggest to write directly to the file, instead in the String Buffer named "content". This has nothing to do with centroids or whatever!

Comment: @Ingo ok, sorry I was looking at the other for loop. The problem is actually not there, I've commented the code. The issue is before when I collect all data in the List object.

Comment: Then you'll need more memory. Have you played around with the -Xmx option?

Comment: @Ingo yeah, this is command line: java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -cp .:jars/* CentroidGenerator data/data.xml

Comment: But I'm puzzled by the fact that my text file is only 329kb, and I will need to parse a 74MB text file (!!!). I'm a bit worried.. do I need a completely different approach.. ? I have 4GB ram on my mac.. I'm afraid I'm not using them

Comment: Hard to tell. If I were you I'd check how much memory the XML parser needs per se - withoud collecting any data at all in the first place. For example, place a "return" in method nextItem to see that.

Comment: @Ingo Are you saying I should use a profiler tool to see it ?

Comment: No. I said: return from nextItem without creating any data, then run the program with the settings you had so far. Depending on your OS, you could also watch some Ressourcemonitor, etc., but important is if the XML parser can parse the file given that much heap. If it can (i.e. no OutOfMemory), see how much you can decrease the -Xmx settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution could be to do 2 passes: first pass computes (and keeps) the changing values in memory, the second pass creates the  output.

Comment: This is exactly what is described in the question... The first pass is over the source file, the second file is over the average values calculated during the first pass...

Comment: @pgras - Yes, you're right, I see it now. But then, the OP is very much confused, because either the number of output items does not depend on the size of the input file, or he failed to tell us in which way.

Comment: the number of output items depends on the size of the input file. The issue here is that I need to keep everything in memory instead of writing on disk. As far as I know (but we are discussing about this in the other post comments)

Answer (score 0):

Does the output fit in RAM, say in a

```
Map<MyItem, Integer>
```

(if your average value fits in an Integer) ?

If the answer is yes, then the fastest solution is to keep it in memory during the source file traversal and then to write the output file.

If the answer is no, you have to partition the problem and create intermediate results and store them to disk, and then you have to merge the intermediate results to create the end result.

If you have to partition the problem, ask a new question with some figures because the answer will really depends on the context...

Comment: The strange thing is that my input file is just 328kb.. and I'm using -Xmx1024m parameter, so.. how comes it doesn't fit.

Comment: Anyway, if the only solution is to create intermediate results, could you give me more information how to do it ? I guess my issue is about storing information while parsing

Comment: @Patrick I just had a look at your CentroidGenerator I found in another question of you. If that is the code you have an OutOfMemoryError with it's normal :) I answered your other question...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [flatpack](http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/) It has LargeDataSet implementation for handling largefiles with less memory.

Comment: If I'm right flatpack can be used to parse files, which doesn't seem to be the problem here...